# Cron job run every N hours (where 24 isn't evenly divisible by N) doesn't work as expected

Tags: cron

For example, if I have a cron job that I want to run every 9 hours:

```
0 */9 * * * my_script
```

The job is executed at 00:00, 9:00, and 18:00; and then the same hours the next day.

What I want is for the job to execute at 00:00, 9:00, 18:00; then 03:00, 12:00, 21:00 the next day -- a true "every 9 hours".

Is there any way make cron job run EVERY 9 hours?

Answer (score 2):

Specifying `*/9` means that the job runs every 9 hours starting at `00:00`. It starts again at `00:00` every day.

There is no syntax in cron to run a job every 9 hours.

What you can do is run a job every 3 hours, and have the command itself examine the current time and only execute 1 time out of 3. Or it can run every hour and execute one time out of every 9. Don't assume that the current time will be exact; it might run a few seconds after the hour.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it's not going to work for me, as I just gave an example, in general I need a way to run my job every N hours, where N can be 5, 11, 14 etc

Comment: As I wrote, "Or it can run every hour and execute one time out of every 9.".  Replace "9" by any number you like.